# Registering user information to various django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

For registration I require the following fields grouped by model:

**UserProfile**

1. Full name
2. Date of birth
3. Occupation

**Address**

1. Street
2. City
3. ZIP
4. State

My question is if I wanted to have only one registration form and one template to save to both of these models, how would I go about getting that done? **I'm using Django@1.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from your app.forms import UserProfileForm, AddressForm


def your_view(request):
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)

    if user_profile_form.is_valid() and address_form.is_valid():
        # creates and returns the new object, persisting it to the database
        user_profile = user_profile_form.save()

        # creates but does not persist the object
        address = AddressForm.save(commit=False)

        # assigns the foreign key relationship
        address.user_profile = user_profile

        # persists the Address model
        address.save()

    return render(request, 'your-template.html',
        {'user_profile_form': user_profile_form,
        'address_form': address_form})
```

The above code assumes there is a `UserProfile` foreign key field on `Address`, and that you have created the above classes inheriting from `ModelForm` for your models.

No offense of course, but a cursory glance at the Django Tutorial should give you a pretty good start on answering this question. Perusing the model and queryset API docs would also be a good place to start.

Django views don't limit the number of form classes you can attempt to hydrate from the data in request.POST.

Comment: Brilliant! I had something similar sketched out, I just needed a clue to tie up all the information I gleaned from the Django docs. Cheers and thanks!